# I met a error warning when run regression model for a panel using plm package

Tags: rstudio

I have a panel for 27 years, but met this warning when I run a regression.
[panel data of global suicide rate with temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEg1A.png)

I use the following codes:

```
library(plm)
install.packages("dummies")
library(dummies)
data2 <- cbind(mydata, dummy(mydata$year, sep ="_"))
suicide_fe <- plm(suiciderate ~ dmt, data2, index = c("country", "year"), 
model= "within")
summary(suicide_fe)
```

But I got this error:

```
Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) : 
duplicate couples (id-time)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pdata.frame(data, index) :
duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame to find out which, use 
e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany") 2: In 
is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
duplicate couples (id-time)
```